# how to display date when clicking a calendar

Tags: android, date

I am implementing a calendar.I have to display a date when it is selected.I got it by using `setOnDateChangeListener` it works fine,but when i click the same date with a few seconds delay it's not showing it.When i click another date it works good. I don't know how to display a date on a click,when it is already selected.

My Activity is,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CalendarView cal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);

    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Selected Date is\n\n"
            +dayOfMonth+" : "+(month+1)+" : "+year , 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   });
  }  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `onDateChangeListener()` only called when you select different date, it is not called when you select already selected date. See this [onDateChanged()][1]


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html#onDateChanged%28android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: @TrushitShah Thank you.is there any other option to display it?

Comment: But why you display already selected date again?

Comment: how about extending the calenderView and listening for touch events

Comment: @RajeshCP Thank you.are you saying about `onTouchEvent` event?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about listening to onTouch event

Comment: Without your custom calendarView its difficult to implement, samples  http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html and http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html

Comment: @KarthickPandiyan Thank you..Those samples helped me to know more about calendar operations.

Comment: Is there any option to manually change the background color of the selected date? It changes automatically ,but is there any other way??